# getting null response if email or password is incorrect in retrofit2

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

i am implementing login web service. i am getting correct response if user email and password is correct. but i am getting null if email or password is incorrect. i want to get message sent from server if email or password is incorrect. My code is below.

```
Call<LoginResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().userLogin(email, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
            System.out.println("body " + response.body());
            System.out.println("response " + response.errorBody().toString());
            sharedPrefManager.cancelDialog();
            if (loginResponse != null) {
                if (loginResponse.getSuccess()) {
                    sharedPrefManager.saveUser(loginResponse.getData(), password);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, loginResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(SignIn.this).cancelDialog();

                    Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            sharedPrefManager.cancelDialog();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

public class RetrofitClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "my_base_url";
private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        //.addInterceptor(new SpeechRecognitionIntercepter())
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

private RetrofitClient() {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public Apis getApi() {
    return retrofit.create(Apis.class);
}
```

}

```
public interface Apis {


@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
Call<LoginResponse> userLogin(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);
```

}

Unsuccessful login response is:

> {
>       "success": false,
>       "message": "Username or Password is incorrect."
>   }

Successful response is:

> {
>       "success": true,
>       "message": "",
>       "data": {
>           "token": "",
>           "name": "Gmail",
>           "picture": "",
>           "userid": 60,
>           "phone": "(111) 114-4444",
>           "email": "tahir123@gmail.com",
>           "company_name": null,
>           "st_address": "Gmail account, Satellite",
>           "location_id": 1,
>           "account_type": 2
>       }
>   }

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from your code if you receive a 200 status even if the call fails, but from what you describe, it seems like you get another http status code.

If this is the case, Retrofit still calls the `onResponse` method, but `response.isSuccessful()` is false and the body will be accessible through the `response.errorBody()` method.

An easy way to get this is:

```
if(response.isSuccessful())
    // Do what you are doing
else {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      LoginResponse error = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string());
      // Use the error variable now
 }
```

There's a lot going on here. Let's start with why do you need manual deserialization. Retrofit doesn't automatically convert the error body for you, you need to do it yourself. Here I've chosen to create a `Gson` instance, which is not elegant, but serves the purpose.

I also chose to use `string()`. This method reads the entire response into memory and can crash for big responses. Calling it will drain the okhttp buffer, which means you won't be able to call it again (to the best of my knowledge), so keep it in a variable if you want to use it multiple times.

Hope this helps